# How to add 2 styles in a component/view in android xml

Tags: android, android-xml, android-styles

I want to add two styles in `ProgressBar`

Here is the xml for ProgressBar

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xxlarge_xxl"/>
```

I have a style defined in `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="genericRegView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/margin_xxlarge_xxl</item>
    </style>
```

I want to apply `genericRegView` to `ProgressBar` but as you can see the it already has a style attached with it. How can I add both?

I know I can inherit styles through names in my style `XML` files but `ProgressBar` style is `?android:attr/progressBarStyle` so I don't know how to inherit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit the `ProgressBar` style using `parent` attribute

```
<style name="genericRegView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/margin_xxlarge_xxl</item>
</style>
```

And apply the `genericRegView` style to the `ProgressBar`

Comment: its giving this error `You must supply a layout_width attribute.` Even though i am defining `layout_width` in style as you can see

Comment: I think because you defined it twice .. in the `ProgressBar` and in the style.. you should define it once .. the same for the `layout_height`

Comment: No, I removed all the repeated code from ProgressBar xml. Basically nothing is being applied of style onto the ProgressBar